# Spray send xls file to client

Tags: excel, download, spray

I'm developing a rest api with spray I need to download from my web-client an excel file with a report.

The excel-generator method is ready but spray's "getFromFile(fileFullPath)" is getting "Internal server error"

Any ideas?

Here is my spray code:

```
(ctx: RequestContext) => {
   val actor = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
      def receive = {
        case GetAnualReport(year, generateExcel) =>
          val flujoActor = context.actorOf(Props[FlujoActor])
          flujoActor ! GetAnualReport(year, generateExcel)
        case ReporteResponse(path) =>
          println("FILE: "+path)
          getFromFile(path)
      }
   }))
actor ! GetAnualReport(year, true)
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
FILE: /tmp/flujocaja-reports-5627299217173924055/reporte-anual.xls
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: This is a rather complicated setup. What's the reason you built your route this way? Have you seen the posts on how to do "per request actors"? E.g. at https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/4714-scala-does-the-catwalk#video or https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is that `getFromFile(path)` doesn't do anything with the request but instead returns a new function `RequestContext => Unit` which is never called. One solution could be to replace that line with `getFromFile(path)(ctx)`.

However, there's a better way how to deal asynchronous work before continuing with an inner route: use futures and one of the [FutureDirectives](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-routing/future-directives/). Here's an example roughly adapted to your use case:

```
onSuccess((flujoActor ? GetAnualReport(year, generateExcel)).mapTo[ReporteResponse]) { response =>
  getFromResource(response.path)
}
```

That said, I'm not sure why you get `500 Internal Server Error` in your scenario. Is there nothing on the console hinting at what the problem is?